# SQL Server combine multiple rows into single row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Any help is much appreciated. I have the following query and need help in modifying it to combine multiple rows into single row with data separated by comma. I have attached the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2G9N.png) for your reference.

```
select CT_ID
     , Acct_Group
     , (source + ' - '
        +  cast(count(*) as nvarchar(20)) 
        +' account groups have total amounts in file A more or less than 25% of File B AMount'
        ) as Error  
from (
     select CT_ID
          , source
          , acct_group
          , sum(balance) as Balance
          , sum(k_new_balance) as K_New_Balance 
     from tblGroups 
     group by acct_group, source, CT_ID 
     ) as x
where abs((K_New_Balance - Balance)/nullif(Balance, 0)) >=0.25 
group by source, CT_ID,Acct_group 
order by CT_ID
```

Comment: you could use pivot for this.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

this might help if you putt the output into a cte or temp table you could use row_number to get the desired outputs like:

```
 select * into #T from (
     select 'l1' CT_ID , 'ab' Acc_Group union
     select 'l1' CT_ID , 'rr' Acc_Group union
     select 'pl1' CT_ID , 'ab' Acc_Group union
     select 'pl1' CT_ID , 'rr' Acc_Group union
     select 'pl1' CT_ID , 'dd' Acc_Group) x



     select x.CT_ID , x.Acc_Group + isnull(','+y.Acc_Group,'') +  isnull(','+z.Acc_Group ,'') Acc_Group,ct.ct

     from (select * ,row_number() over ( partition by CT_ID order by Acc_Group) rowid    from #T) x
     left join (select * ,row_number() over ( partition by CT_ID order by Acc_Group) rowid   from #T) y
     on x.rowid = y.rowid -1
     and x.CT_ID = y.CT_ID
     left join (select * ,row_number() over ( partition by CT_ID order by Acc_Group) rowid   from #T) z
     on x.rowid = z.rowid -2
     and x.CT_ID = z.CT_ID
     left join ( select CT_ID,count(*) ct from #T group by CT_ID) ct
     on ct.CT_ID = x.CT_ID
     where x.rowid = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a google search for "sql string concatenation"

An example from one of the first results: https://sqlandme.com/2011/04/27/tsql-concatenate-rows-using-for-xml-path/

```
SELECT      CAT.Name AS [Category],
            STUFF((    SELECT ',' + SUB.Name AS [text()]
                — Add a comma (,) before each value
                    FROM Production.ProductSubcategory SUB
                    WHERE
                    SUB.ProductCategoryID = CAT.ProductCategoryID
                    FOR XML PATH('') — Select it as XML
                    ), 1, 1, '' )
                    — This is done to remove the first character (,)
                    — from the result
        AS [Sub Categories]
FROM  Production.ProductCategory CAT
```

Basically, allows you to join results of a sub-query as a delimited list (in this case, a comma), as a result. You could then include that in your sub-query to select all the codes.